# Tensorflow Dataset created with from_generator not iterating by batch_size

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've created a tensorflow dataset from a generator but can't figure out how to iterate over it by batch_size

```py
def ds_gen():
    x = np.random.random((10, 10, 3))
    y = np.random.random((2))
    yield x, y

def create_tf_dataset():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(ds_gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes=((10, 10, 3), (2,)))
    return dataset

ds = create_tf_dataset()
ds = ds.batch(10)
for x_batch, y_batch in ds:
  print(x_batch.shape, y_batch.shape)
```

This code keeps looping over batch sizes of 1 as opposed to 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer code in below to iterate by batch size

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 

def ds():
    for i in range(1000):
      x = np.random.rand(10,10,3)
      y = np.random.rand(2)
      yield x,y

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(ds, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes=((10, 10, 3), (2,)))

ds = ds.batch(10)

for batch, (x,y) in enumerate(ds):
  pass
print("Data shape: ", x.shape, y.shape)
```

Output:

```
Data shape:  (10, 10, 10, 3) (10, 2)
```

If you change `ds = ds.batch(1)` then output will be `Data shape:  (1, 10, 10, 3) (1, 2)`